# What is the mean from "N: Can't drop privileges for downloading as file"?

Tags: 16.04, apt, software-installation

i was successfully installed atom but from offline package and at the end of installation show this message? anyone can explain it? thx B4...

> N: Can't drop privileges for downloading as file '/home/kk2id/Desktop/atom-amd64.deb' couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)

Comment: It is a common but see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-notifier/+bug/1570141

Comment: Correct bug-report is https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/synaptic/+bug/1522675

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the *Chai T. Rex* method for single install:

```
sudo apt -o APT::Sandbox::User=root install --reinstall ./package-name.deb
```

---

As I already wrote in [comment 80 of bug-report 1522675](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/synaptic/+bug/1522675/comments/80):

> I removed warning messages by setting `APT::Sandbox::User` to `"root"` with
>
> ```
> cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99z-anti-drop
> APT::Sandbox::User "root";
>
> EOF
> ```
>
> I do not know is it secure or not. But it works as expected!

It removes such warnings permanently. You can use it at your own risk.

Comment: It's probably better to use the nonpermanent `sudo apt -o APT::Sandbox::User=root install --reinstall ./atom-amd64.deb`

Comment: thank you, it's been long time since i learn ubuntu :)